# the use of "+" in sed regular expression

Tags: regex, linux

```
echo "  lfj"|sed -e "s/^\s+//g"
  lfj
```

I remember `+` indicates `one or more`, so there's two white spaces in front of `lfj`, why cannot it strip them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `+`.

```
$ echo "  lfj"|sed -e "s/^\s\+//g"
lfj
```

Basic sed uses BRE(Basic REgular Expressions). To make `+` to repeat the previous character one or more times in BRE, you need to escape it.

Enable the extended regexp option `-r` in sed to make sed to use ERE instead of BRE.

```
$ echo "  lfj"|sed -r "s/^\s+//g"
lfj
```

Comment: Yep, you don't need to escape the `*` but you must escape the `+` in sed which uses BRE

Answer (score 1):

Use -r

```
echo "  lfj"|sed -re "s/^\s+//g"
```

From http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

```
A quick comment. The original sed did not support the "+" metacharacter. GNU sed does if 
you use the "-r" command line option, which enables extended regular expressions. The "+" 
means "one or more matches".
```

also from https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

```
-r
--regexp-extended
Use extended regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions. Extended regexps 
are those that egrep accepts; they can be clearer because they usually have less backslashes, 
but are a GNU extension and hence scripts that use them are not portable.
```